# Opening PYD files with 7zip

Tags: python, cython

I'm trying to get the source code of a python program and have come to realize that is it likely Cython due to a ton of **`*.pyd`** files in the library.zip. I don't have experience with these; however I have noticed I can open this .pyd file in 7zip giving me the following files:

[image]

my question is can any of these be decompiled into a python source? I cannot find anything regarding actually opening the PYD file with 7zip - there is a general thread about decompiling however it never mentions anywhere about the files found when you open it with 7zip.

Comment: it seems 7zip is able to open general dll or pyd file and mapped them according to section categories (data, code) but they are still in binaries.